Se puede reemplazar localhost por una ip automaticamente?
la cosa es que en el trabajo tenemos una plataforma que funciona desde el servidor de la compañia, sin embargo una parte de esta pagina te redirecciona a otra, el problema es que queda en formato
localhost:1234/example
pero este no funciona, al hacerl el cambio manualmente con la ip correspiente ya funciona
123.45.6.789:1234/example
sin embargo no podemos tener a todos los funcionarios haciendo esto por lo que quiero saber si es posible que el cambio se realice de manera automatica

Y porque no usan el Server Name en lugar de todo lo que ya tienen? Es en una LAN? Como has instalado Apache?

si. y depende de como este hecha toda la pagina, pero no podes tener en ningun lado de tu pagina una ruta absoluta como esa...

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

la plataforma no nos permite cambiar la direccion que se utiliza, el enlace siempre sale como localhost:1234/example
si no es esto a lo que te referias me podrias explicar?

Y si los redirigis? Con javascript podría ser location.href = "123.45.6.789:1234" +location.pathname
